# How to use a NUXT component in another site

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a working NUXT application with various pages and components in `universal` mode. Now I need to render one of the components on another static html site.

I can easily export a regular Vue application's component just adding a bundle script and div element to which the components renders.

But how can I do it with NUXT?

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt is not really meant for a quick plug (with a script tag) but for an SSR usage (with some NodeJS build), so I **highly** doubt that you can make this. Or at least, I don't really see the point if you only use it as an SPA component.

If somebody knows a solution to make it work, I'm all yours on your opinion on this.